# Hyperledger Fabric - Error while trying to open DB: sync Invalid Argument

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to start Ordering Service but getting the following Error.

```
panic: Error while trying to open DB: sync /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/index: invalid argument
```

> orderer.example.com    | panic: Error while trying to open DB: sync /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/index: invalid argument
>   orderer.example.com    |
>   orderer.example.com    | goroutine 1 [running]:
>   orderer.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper.(*DB).Open(0xc4202b3280)
>   orderer.example.com    |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper/leveldb_helper.go:88 +0x27f
>   orderer.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper.NewProvider(0xc4203e94a0, 0xc4203e94a0)
>   orderer.example.com    |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/util/leveldbhelper/leveldb_provider.go:40 +0xe8
>   orderer.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage.NewProvider(0xc4203f5300, 0xc4203f5320, 0x4c9a08d, 0xc42031b900)
>   orderer.example.com    |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blkstorage/fsblkstorage/fs_blockstore_provider.go:34 +0x80
>   orderer.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blockledger/file.New(0xc420147ef0, 0x23, 0x2, 0x2)
>   orderer.example.com    |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/ledger/blockledger/file/factory.go:71 +0xf2
>   orderer.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.createLedgerFactory(0xc420274a00, 0xc4203ee780, 0x30, 0x30, 0xcb5a40)
>   orderer.example.com    |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/util.go:32 +0x23c
>   orderer.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.initializeMultichannelRegistrar(0xc420274a00, 0x138cd00, 0x13f0d60, 0xc420112908, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc4203e8ca0)
>   orderer.example.com    |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:246 +0x43
>   orderer.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Start(0xcf829c, 0x5, 0xc420274a00)
>   orderer.example.com    |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:99 +0x24c
>   orderer.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
>   orderer.example.com    |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:78 +0x13a
>   orderer.example.com    | main.main()
>   orderer.example.com    |    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
>   orderer.example.com exited with code 2

I'm using hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.1.0-alpha image for orderer and also properly generated Crypto material for my peers and organization.

Please help.